# Creating a right-click menu option and receiving information from file in order to manipulate

Tags: java, windows, file

So I'm not 100% sure if I explained it correctly in the title, but I will try and explain it more thoroughly here.

Let's say I want to make a Java application that receives a file, and simply makes a duplicate. This is pretty simple to do when specifying the desired file's path in console, or an input box, etc. However, what I wish to do is to, for example, add a right click option to the user's window (which I believe I know how to do), this right click option would have the name "Duplicate", and it would take the file that the menu option was clicked on, and duplicate it.

The only problem I am having right now, is understanding how I can get the file information after pressing the menu option?

TLDR: Right click a file, select "Duplicate", which runs my application, application receives file info (somehow?) and duplicates the file.

Comment: Your Java app receives the file path as a command line argument.

Comment: @pingw33n Thanks, I figured it out.